# Binning dates without displaying every bin on the x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a file full of date-and-value pairs. I want to bin the points by month and then display a box-and-whisker plot. My problem is that I have many months’ worth of data and so I only want to show *some* of the x-axis labels.

My code looks like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(scales)

data <- read.delim("values.tsv", header=TRUE)

# Interpret the strings as dates
data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")

# Bin the data by month
data$Date <- cut(data$Date, breaks="1 month")

ggplot(data, aes(factor(Date), Temperature)) +
    geom_boxplot()

ggsave("output.pdf", width=8, height=6, units="in")
```

Here is some sample data in the appropriate format:

```
Date    Temperature
2016-09-29 07:16:00 -0500   295.0
2016-09-30 07:23:00 -0500   295.0
2016-10-03 10:27:00 -0500   297.8
2016-10-04 07:27:00 -0500   296.2
2016-10-26 05:52:00 -0500   294.2
2016-10-27 06:18:00 -0500   294.2
2016-10-28 07:41:00 -0500   294.2
2016-11-27 09:07:00 -0500   293.6
2016-11-30 08:03:00 -0500   295.0
2016-12-01 08:12:00 -0500   295.0
2016-12-02 08:01:00 -0500   293.2
2016-12-07 08:02:00 -0500   294.6
2016-12-08 07:50:00 -0500   294.6
2016-12-09 08:37:00 -0500   293.2
2016-12-12 08:25:00 -0500   294.4
2016-12-13 07:47:00 -0500   293.2
2016-12-14 07:52:00 -0500   294.6
2017-01-09 07:53:00 -0500   294.0
2017-01-10 08:26:00 -0500   294.4
2017-01-11 08:20:00 -0500   294.6
2017-01-31 08:16:00 -0500   290.6
2017-02-07 07:59:00 -0500   290.8
2017-02-08 08:10:00 -0500   290.6
2017-02-09 08:33:00 -0500   291.2
2017-02-10 07:57:00 -0500   290.4
2017-02-13 07:48:00 -0500   290.4
2017-02-28 08:19:00 -0500   291.8
```

The real data consists of several hundred data points across forty months. The data are being binned correctly but when I try to add a scale via

```
scale_x_date(date_breaks="4 months", date_labels="%b '%y")
```

I get the error

> Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

It seems that `cut` converts the input Dates to something else—strings, I assume. How do I convert the x-axis values back to dates so that I can apply `scale_x_date` to them?

Comment: Did you check the class of `Date` before the plot ? However, I think that even if they are dates, by calling `aes(factor(Date)` you're transforming them into factors again inside the ggplot call. Therefore I don't think that `scale_x_date` can work.

Comment: @LorenzoBusetto Yes—if I leave out that `cut` call then I can successfully use `scale_x_date` later. I assume that that means that `Date` really did contain dates before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `cut` is transforming your data into a factor, so it's not a date anymore, and therefore `scale_x_date` can't be applied.

We can work around this by creating a one-month grouping variable for your boxplot and grouping the observations in your `aes` call.

```
data$Month <- cut(data$Date, breaks="1 month")

ggplot(data, aes(Date, Temperature, group = Month)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks="4 months", date_labels="%b '%y")
```

X is still a date, but your observations are grouped for the purposes of the plot. I'm having trouble uploading the plot, but based on your sample data I believe it's working correctly.